# Connecting Access Points WLAN port with brlan port

Tags: ip, openwrt

I have two laptops: Laptop A and Laptop B. I have one TP-link Access Point with one WAN port and multiple br-LAN ports.

I have configured all the devices (Laptop A, Laptop B and Access Point) to the same subnet.

Laptop A 192.168.1.4

Laptop B 192.168.1.2

Access Point (brlan port) 192.168.1.12

Access Point (wan port)  192.168.1.1

Experiment 1:
Laptop A and Laptop B connected to the br-lan ports of the AP and I tried to ping each other.
The connection is successful.

Experiment 2:
Laptop A is connected to the br-lan port and Laptop B is connected to the WAN port. However this time I cannot ping the laptops from each other.

I tried to ping the access point from Laptop B doesnot hear.
Similarly I tried to ping Laptop B from Access POint(Using OpenWRT root connection) cannot hear.

My assumption was since everything belongs to the same subnet it should work as a LAN. However it is not happening.

Any idea why not?

Answer (score 0):

WLAN stands for Wireless Local Area Network so I would not expect ethernet port with this marking.
It would make more sense if it is WAN port as Wild Area Network which is your Internet connection.

WAN port is Layer3 interface and would not be bridged with LAN interfaces.

If you in fact have WLAN port, please provide the exact model of your device.

Comment: Model is TPLINK TL-WDR4300.

Comment: Model is TPLINK TL-WDR4300. Sorry it will be WAN port. However if we look at the routing protocol, any packet from LAN to the internet goes through the WAN port. For me the backend or the internet or server is one of my laptops. How will I connect one laptop that is in LAN to the WAN one?